# How common were cybernetics in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars*, how many characters have cybernetic enhancements?

In *The Empire Strikes Back*, Luke has his severed hand replaced shortly after losing it.

Anakin also has most of his arm replaced in *Attack of the Clones*; later, he becomes more machine than man with cybernetics.

Commander Wolffe also gets a cybernetic eye.

General Grievous has most of his body replaced by cybernetics. However, his organs still appear mostly intact.

The technology seems to perfectly replicate the mechanics of a human hand/arm/eye/cardiovascular system/respiratory system/skin.

**Would it be considered a common medical practice to replace lost/damaged body parts with Cybernetics? Or Were these procedures considered available to only elite characters?**

At first it seems fairly common however the three characters mentioned above may be considered special enough to have an uncommon medical procedure executed:

1. Luke: Hero of the Rebel Alliance to Restore the Republic, leader of Rouge/Red Squadron, Friends with Princess/General Leia Organa.
2. Anakin: Jedi Knight at the height of their power during a war with a nearly blank check policy.
3. Darth Vader: Sith Lord during tyrannical rule of Sith Empire. Apprentice to said Empire's leader.
4. Commander Wolf: Commander with some skill over the standard trooper. He also had a personal relationship with Jedi Master Plo Koon, who may have more pull to help out Wolf.
5. General Grievous: Second in command to the Separatist Army. A tool to be used by Darth Sidious and en elite warrior in his own right.

Comment: [Subjects of Cybernetic Enhancements](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cybernetics/Legends#Subjects_of_cybernetic_replacements.2Fenhancements)?

Comment: Are you interested only in films and the animated series? No novels/comics?

Comment: In your list, you are forgetting the best example of cybernetics - General Grievous

Comment: @psubsee2003 I realized that last night as well :)

Comment: comics are canon @Gallifreyan (as I'm sure you know) so unless they tag it Legends, I think novels and comics are fair game, and, on that front: Darth Vader Vol 2 (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Vader_Volume_2_%E2%80%94_Shadows_and_Secrets) has a cadre of characters w/ cybernetic enhancements  - re: the question - what do you mean by "common" - like an actual ratio or are you asking for a list of all cybernetically enhanced characters or what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cybernetics were common enough that a noodle shop owner named [Lauli Wahlo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lauli_Wahlo) was able to afford a cybernetic right eye:

[image: Lauli Wahlo and his cybernetic eye]

Wahlo's artificial eye is much more simplistic than the cybernetics we've seen on main characters, though, so it's possible that only the wealthiest and/or most important could afford something as nice as Luke's artificial hand.

It's hard to say how common cybernetics really were since not many characters use them (even Wookieepedia's Legends article for cybernetics has only a [short list of mostly major characters who had cybernetic enhancements](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cybernetics/Legends#Subjects_of_cybernetic_replacements.2Fenhancements)).

Answer (score 0):

Cybernetic *enhancements* are widely available, as there's a lot of cross compatibility between droid parts and medical prosthetics to the point that when Jedi Knight Cay Qel-Droma lost his arm on Onderon, he literally just pulled a droid arm out of a scrap pile and was able to just stick it onto his stump once they were out of danger.

So pretty much anyone with sufficient motivation to do so can enhance themselves with cybernetics, although unless they have credits to burn they won't be very pretty.

Now, simple replacements to lost parts looks to be far more common, with anyone who loses a hand or tentacle will often replace it with some sort of prosthetic. Even though cloning replacement body parts is also fairly common. Arkanians, for example, make medical cloning a huge part of their economy. Of course, as with the aforementioned Cay Quel-Droma, it seems to be a simple task to just use droid parts, which are positively ubiquitous, as cheap prosthetics.